# Did Jesus commit the HOLY spirit in to the hands of the father ? Luke 23:44-48

Tags: jesus, cross

From Luke's GOSPEL
I am asking last word of Jesus at the cross:

> Luke 23:46 - Then Jesus called out in a loud voice, “Father, into Your
> hands I commit My spirit.” And when He had said this, He breathed His
> last.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 8):

There are a few conspicuous things about Luke 23:46 that answer the OP question.

1. Just before expiring, Jesus quotes Ps 31:5 -

> Into Your hands I commit my spirit [spoken by David]

Exactly the same prayer was uttered by Stephen before he died as recorded in Acts 7:59 -

> While they were stoning him, Stephen appealed, “Lord Jesus, receive my
> spirit.”

Even Mary, the mother of Jesus, used a similar expression when expressing her joy in Luke 1:47 -

> and my spirit rejoices in God my Savior!

Many times, Paul used a similar expression as recorded in Rom 1:9, 1 Cor 5:4, 14:14, 15, 16:18, 2 Cor 2:13, etc.

Since David, nor Stephen, nor Mary, nor Paul had a monopoly on the Holy Spirit, they were all referring to something more personal, as was Jesus.

2. There is a subtle word-play in Luke 23:46 - the verb (in Greek as in English) 'to expire' = ἐκπνέω (ekpneo) is closely related to 'aspirate' = πνέω (pneo) and 'spirit' = πνεῦμα (pneuma).  Thus, in an attempt to better show the word-play, we could literally translate Luke 23:46 -

> And having called out in a loud voice, Jesus said, "Father, into [the]
> hands of You I commit the spirit of Me". Then having said, He expired
> [breathed out].

This is a direct allusion to Eccl 12:7 -

> before the dust returns to the ground from which it came and the
> spirit returns to God who gave it.

Thus, Jesus is simply saying, as all other humans must, that God keeps their spirit at death, the reverse of the process described in Gen 2:7 -

> Then the LORD God formed man from the dust of the ground and breathed
> the breath [= spirit] of life into his nostrils, and the man became a
> living being [lit: 'soul'].

Answer (score 0):

No, it is the His human, created spirit or soul that He committed to the Father. It is the same as Stephen, when dying, said similarly: “receive my soul” (Acts 7:59), as said in Ecclesiastes 12:7 : “And the dust returns to the earth as it was, and the spirit returns to God who gave it”.

It is with this created human spirit or soul that the uncreated Person of Logos descended to hell and preached and gladdened the spirits or souls of deceased humans, as old-time humans as those of the time of Noah’s deluge (1 Peter 3:19), despite of what Jehova Witnessists unbiblically say about co-death of soul with body.